# Cannot run Python module from command line

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

I am attempting to install a package from github (https://github.com/sina-al/pynlp). To run the package, the instructions say to run `python3 -m pynlp`
. However, when I run this I receive the error:

```
adamg:~ adamg$ python3 -m pynlp
/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.5: Error while finding spec for 'pynlp.__main__' (<class 'ImportError'>: No module named 'corenlp_protobuf'); 'pynlp' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

How can this be corrected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you follow all the instructions on GitHub? 1) downloading the Stanford CoreNLP 
2) set an environmental variable `CORE_NLP` that points to it

then:
3) `pip3 install corenlp_protobuf` (if it's missing)

Comment: Thanks! That worked. But that instruction isn't in the README

Comment: Yes, I sent a pull request to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In the event that you get the error message below, you most likely have a problem with your `PATH` environment variable.

```
C:\>python
  File "C:\Python\Python3\lib\site.py", line 178
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This may happen if you have more than one Python instance on your system, e.g. Python 2.x and Python 3.x or Anaconda. For me, I had 3 instances of Python, and there was no issue until after a system update.

To resolve this issue you have to edit your PATH settings.

- Open up Windows Explorer (Win-E) and right click on "This PC" and select properties.
- From the Properties dialog, click the "Advanced system settings" link, and in the dialog box that opens, click on the "Environment Variables..." button at the bottom.
- Look for duplicate PATH variables that point to Python installations, and remove all but the one you use most commonly.

In my case, I deleted all references to Python2.7, as I'm now using Python 3.x.